# Как подождать 5 секунд?

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

Нужно чтобы программа подождала 5 секунд и потом дальше выполняла код.

Среда разработки Lazarus (free pascal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень просто:

```
Sleep(5000); // время задаётся в миллисекундах
```

Однако есть тонкость: при нежелании подключении модуля Windows следует использовать команду `Delay(5000);`:)